# Controller Action method not called while using dependency injection in asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The controller action method is not been called while using the constructor.

Here is the startup class.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<EmakitiContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddTransient<IMarketUOW<EmakitiContext>, MarketUow<EmakitiContext>> ();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

When I added a constructor on the Homecontroller the action method is not been called.However, if I remove the constructor then the action method will be called. What I am doing wrong I am not able to figure it out.

Here is the controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[Action]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private readonly IMarketUOW<EmakitiContext> _iMarketUow;

        public HomeController(IMarketUOW<EmakitiContext> iMarketUow )
        {
            _iMarketUow = iMarketUow;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>> GetMarketList()
        {
            GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>> genericResponseObject = new GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>>();
            genericResponseObject.IsSuccess = false;
            genericResponseObject.Message = ConstaintStingValue.Tag_ConnectionFailed;
            try
            {
                genericResponseObject.Data = _iMarketUow.GetMarketList();
                genericResponseObject.IsSuccess = true;
                genericResponseObject.Message = ConstaintStingValue.Tag_ConnectionSuccess;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

            }
            return genericResponseObject;
        }


    }
}
```

Here is the Market Interface Class

```
 public interface IMarketUOW<C> where C: DbContext
    {
        List<MarketViewModel> GetMarketList();
    }
```

Here is the marketuow implement class

```
public class MarketUow<C> : IMarketUOW<C> where C : DbContext
    {

        private readonly IGenericRepository<C, Market> _iGenericRepository;

        public MarketUow(IGenericRepository<C, Market> iGenericRepository)
        {
            _iGenericRepository = iGenericRepository;
        }

        public List<MarketViewModel> GetMarketList()
        {
            List<MarketViewModel> listMarket = new List<MarketViewModel>();
            var databaseList = _iGenericRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            databaseList.ForEach(m => listMarket.Add(new MarketViewModel
            {
                MarketId = m.MarketId,
                City = m.City,
                CityF = m.CityF,
                IsActive = m.IsActive,
                Name = m.Name,
                NameF = m.NameF,
                SortOrder = m.SortOrder
            }));
            return listMarket;

        }

    }
```

Here is the Generic Interface code

```
public interface IGenericRepository<C,T> where C: DbContext where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetAll();
        IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

        void Add(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Edit(T entity);
        void Save();

    }
```

Here is the Generic Implementation class

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<C,T> : IGenericRepository<C, T> where T: class where C: DbContext, new()
    {
        private C _entities =new C();
        public C Context
        {

            get { return _entities; }
            set { _entities = value; }
        }       

        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {

            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
            return query;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {

            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
            return query;
        }

        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Edit(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual void Save()
        {
            _entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add template of `MarketUow` class in question as well.

Comment: @Ahmar - I have updated the complete code. Please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Home controller only initialize when its all dependency fulfill. Dependency Injunction try to instantiate  `MarketUow` which depend on `GenericRepository`. Then it try to instantiate it but not able to do this because it abstract class.

Add this in startup

```
services.AddTransient< IGenericRepository< EmakitiContext,Market>, GenericRepository<EmakitiContext, Market>>();
services.AddTransient<IMarketUOW<EmakitiContext>, MarketUow<EmakitiContext>>();
```

and remove abstract modifier from `GenericRepository` and it will run.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually missing to tell how to manage the dependency injection for `IMarketUOW<EmakitiContext>` interface.

In `Startup.cs` in `ConfigureServices` you have to add:

```
services.AddTransient<IMarketUOW, MarketUow>();
services.AddScoped(typeof(IMarketUOW<>), typeof(MarketUow<>));
```

Comment: I added in startup.cs but still same problem

Comment: As you said that without the controller it was working, I'm pretty sure it's a dependency injection issue and ASP does not know how to instantiate your controller with the parameter. I will have a closer look

Comment: I have updated the startup.cs file please let me know

Comment: Could you try just with: `services.AddTransient<typeof(IMarketUOW<>), typeof(MarketUow<>)> ();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131208/discussion-between-piou-and-san-jaisy).

Comment: Can you please check the code where I am missing I have uploaded the full code